# An Auto Click for a webpage tab that I will not intrude on my cursor used for other tabs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, developer-tools, inspect-element

Im looking for an autoclicker extension, software, it can be JavaScript, but I need it to be where I just paste into the console of inspect element. Where it just requires me to move my mouse to the exact location. To lockdown the coordinates of where to autoclick on the tab that I am currently using. For this particular example it would be used on Facebook for clicking a button that horizontally scrolls more profiles of continuously until it reaches the end. However, I still want to be able to freely use my mouse on other tabs once I make this one no longer active. Without the fear of it no longer working due to being in the background, or by the autoclicking taking effect on where ever I position the mouse after

so if you have a JavaScript code that can do that great. Otherwise, please just suggest extensions, software, or etc that can do the job.

as previously stated I want to still be able to click, scroll or move my mouse on other tabs while the auto click is working on the selective tab. I do not want to have to relinquish control of my mouse until the procedure is done.

There is the auto clicker by murgee, that will do what I am requesting, but it requires a monthly subscription instead of a one time payment

Now if any of you require a one time payment for your extension, software, or whatever it is that you conjure to perform the request. I will be more then happy to oblige. I just cant do a monthly, or a yearly subscription, it needs to be a one time payment,

So please anyone who can suggest or share with me what they created that will complete this task would be hugely appreciative.

I have tried a few extensions and software's none however have resolved my issue except Murgee But I am not willing to do a monthly payment.